# How to perform a addition in Jinja2?

Tags: html, css, jinja2

I would like to add a value to a variable.

I thought of something similar:

```
{% set highscore = 0 %}
{% highscore = highscore+3 %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are suggesting could be accomplished like this:

```
{% set highscore = 0 %}
{% set highscore = highscore + 3 %}
```

But be cautious about using jinja2 variable assignment... Especially as it relates to [scoping](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#assignments_)

Comment: This gives error:

TemplateSyntaxError at /csv-display/data-display/
Invalid block tag on line 33: 'set', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?